# python import lxml from own directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have assignment a python3 script, where I use **lxml** library, especially: `from lxml import etree`. But on computer, where it will tested isn't **lxml** installed, however I can append this library to my script. I copied **lxml** to my folder. There are many files and I have no idea how to import it to my script. Could you give me any advice?

Comment: `pip install lxml`

Comment: We were told it won't be installed there.

Comment: Where it won't be installed ?

Comment: We have assignment to school and they will be testing it on a school server. They told us they won't install it but we can append it to our script with files which we will upload.

Comment: That's going to be difficult for `lxml`. It depends on the library `libxml2` so some sort of installation is required. You could switch to the pure-python ElementTree.